# CS сервер в локальной сети

Tags: сервер, сокеты, порты

Собственно проблема - не видно запускаемый сервер из локальной сети. Посмотрел порты и вот что выдало

```
# sockstat|grep hlroot     
hlds_i686            3703     udp4   192.168.1.194:27015       *:*                       CLOSED
root     hlds_i686            3703     udp4   192.168.1.194:26900       *:*     CLOSED
```

Отсюда имеем что порты рабочие - закрыты. Чем решить,куда копать?) Правила iptables разрешают все. Запускал командой `./hlds_run -game cstrike -insecure -nomaster +sv_lan 1 +ip 192.168.1.194`

Answer (score 1):

> iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING  -p udp --dport 27015 -j DNAT
>   --to-destination 192.168.1.194:27015 iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING  -p udp --dport 26900 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.194:26900

Это если твой сервак за натом ....... то  это надо на шлюзе прописывать ....